# NTP monitoring issue

Tags: cisco, ntp

I have set up a measurement in our monitoring tool to check the state of the NTP, the target is a Nexus 5596, i'm using the following oid :

1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.168.1.1.11

But I'm getting : *snmp_entry_value_check: OID unavailable, value check skipped*

Anybody can share how he check the NTP on his cisco switches ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you used the Cisco MIB Locator to see which are available for your device and IOS version?

Comment: I didn't find the one for Nexus 5596

Comment: Then, I suppose, that device doesn't have that, and you are getting exactly what you should get.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Many Cisco devices don't allow you to find out clock data through SNMP.  For practical purposes I use a simple SNTP client which does SNTP-query then syslog.

Perhaps that's of some use.

Kind regards

Jonathan.